# Custom Login Page redirects to Sitecore default Login Page

Tags: authentication

I tried setting up a `<site>` element on my Project layer with parameters `requiredLogin="true" loginPage="/Login" domain="extranet"`

I also have granted these items with Read access:

`sitecore/content/SiteItem`

`sitecore/content/SiteItem/Home`

`sitecore/content/SiteItem/Home/Login`

when I try to visit the page via `{url}/Login` it redirects me to the default Sitecore login page.

Am I missing some steps here?

Comment: can you try setting the full item path
e.g. loginPage="/sitecore/content/SiteItem/Home/Login"

Comment: @josedbaez same result, however when my property is `loginPage="/login"` the redirect Url is `{url}/sitecore/login?returnUrl=404` (something like that) so the redirect works, it's just that the read access doesn't seem to not be taking effect

Comment: does extranet/anonymous user have access to login item?

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache/cookies or in an incognito window?

Comment: yes, extranet/anonymous has Read access to login item

Comment: yes, the page is viewed on an incognito window